# Убрать повторение условия

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if

Можно как-то избавить код от повторения условия

```
tweet_words = [word for word in text.split() if not word.startswith('@')
                   if not word.startswith('#') if not word.startswith('http')]
```

Пыталась так, но он дублирует слова три раза:

```
tweet_words = [word for word in text.split() for i in ['@', 'http', '#'] if not word.startswith(i)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [`startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) позволяет в качестве аргумента передать кортеж параметров:

```
tweet_words = [word for word in text.split() if not word.startswith(('@', '#', 'http'))]
```

Comment: спасибо, я единственное в кортеж не оборачивала, буду знать на будущее))